# Why in cryptography we use modular arithmetic for encryption? What's the intuition behind it?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I was studying various cryptographic encryption schemes and why modular arithmetic is being used so much while encrypting messages. Why don't we use simple multiplication with a large known prime with the message, as factorizing large numbers takes exponential time complexity, so it would be hard for an intruder to decrypt the message?

So, simply using an encryption scheme that multiplies a large prime on the message to be encrypted is also hard to decrypt for an intruder without knowledge of the prime number multiplied.

Why was there a need felt for modular arithmetic-based encryption schemes?

wanted just a motivation why we should study modular arithmetic...

Comment: If you're studying areas of mathematics like group theory, an application of modular arithmetic is shown as being used for encoding. But yes of course, there are more sophisticated methods. Here is widely known one that is ~50 years old: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: modular arithmetic allows us to efficiently work with integers in large powers without actually calculating some integer in a large power (Fermat's little theorem)

Comment: yes, sorry exponential time complexity so, simply using an encryption scheme that multiplies a large prime to the message to be encrypted is also hard to decrypt for an intruder without the knowledge of the prime number multiplied why there was a need for modular arithmetic-based encryption schemes?

Comment: We use modular arithmetic because it works. There is no intuition to have. We're you to come up with a completely different idea to base encryption on, and it works better, we will use that too.

Comment: Since the individual letters are represented as numbers, for example ASCII has 128 numbered letters, in the end any cipher has to map back to these same 128 numbers... From the earliest ciphers, eg. transposition cipher N = (N + k) mod 128, to modern RSA/AES ciphers, modular arithmetic probably has to be used somewhere to map back the numbers into the same closed 128-member set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorising large numbers is only difficult if the number has *at least two* distinct very large prime factors. Multiplication by a large prime could therefore only be used to securely encrypt messages whose plaintexts had at least one very large prime factor. And if a stickybeak were to obtain *just two* messages encrypted with the same prime number $\ p\ $, he or she would nearly always be able to recover $\ p\ $ by taking the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the two encrypted messages, since it's unlikely that both plaintexts would be divisible by the same sufficiently large prime to prevent recovery of $\ p\ $ from the gcd of the encrypted texts. Even if this were to happen, it's virtually certain that interception of a third message encrypted with $\ p\ $ would enable the interceptor to recover it.